# Position 1 Keyword SEARCH not expected. Valid tokens: ) FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Below is my attempt at recursively querying all of the dependency catalogs for a given object:

```
Create or Replace Procedure DEPCAT( Out OBJECT_SCHEMA char(20),
                                     Out OBJECT_NAME Char(20),
                                      OBJECT_TYPE char(20),
                                     DupX char(1))


/* Environment */
Specific DEPCAT
Language SQL
Modifies SQL Data

Begin

Declare DuplicateError CHAR (1);

WITH DEPENDENCY_CHAIN_BASE                                          
(REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,REQ_OBJECT_NAME,REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                         
DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_NAME,DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                                  
DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME,
REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER,
DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE)                                            
AS (SELECT D.OBJECT_SCHEMA AS REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.OBJECT_NAME AS                                            
REQ_OBJECT_NAME,D.OBJECT_TYPE AS REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                           
D.VARIABLE_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.VARIABLE_NAME AS
DEP_OBJECT_NAME, 'VARIABLE' AS DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                                 
 SYSTEM_VAR_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_SCHEMA, SYSTEM_VAR_NAME AS                                          
  DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME, '' AS REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,
  V.VARIABLE_DEFINER AS DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER, D.PARM_SIGNATURE AS
  DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10000)                                             
           FOR BIT DATA) AS REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE                                           
  FROM SYSVARIABLEDEP D                                         
  JOIN SYSVARIABLES V ON V.VARIABLE_NAME=D.VARIABLE_NAME                                            
                     AND V.VARIABLE_SCHEMA=D.VARIABLE_SCHEMA                                            
UNION ALL                                           
SELECT D.OBJECT_SCHEMA AS REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.OBJECT_NAME AS                                            
REQ_OBJECT_NAME,D.OBJECT_TYPE AS REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                           
 D.TABLE_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.TABLE_NAME AS
 DEP_OBJECT_NAME, 'MATERIALIZED QUERY TABLE' AS DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,
 D.SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_SCHEMA,
D.SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME AS DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME,
 AS REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,T.TABLE_DEFINER AS DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER,                                           
 D.PARM_SIGNATURE AS DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,
 CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10000) FOR BIT DATA) AS
 REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE FROM SYSTABLEDEP D                                           
 JOIN SYSTABLES T ON T.TABLE_NAME=D.TABLE_NAME AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA
   =D.TABLE_SCHEMA                                          
UNION ALL                                           
SELECT D.EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA AS REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,
D.EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE AS REQ_OBJECT_NAME,                                            
       CASE T.TABLE_TYPE WHEN 'A' THEN 'ALIAS'                                          
            WHEN 'L' THEN 'LF'                                          
            WHEN 'M' THEN 'MATERIALIZED QUERY TABLE'                                            
            WHEN 'P' THEN 'PF'                                          
            WHEN 'T' THEN 'TABLE'                                           
            WHEN 'V' THEN 'VIEW'                                            
            ELSE 'OTHER' END AS REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                            
       D.TRIGGER_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.TRIGGER_NAME
       AS DEP_OBJECT_NAME, 'TRIGGER' AS DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                            
       SYSTEM_TRIGGER_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_SCHEMA,
       TRIGGER_PROGRAM_NAME AS DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME,                                          
    BASE_TABLE_CATALOG AS REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,D.TRIGGER_DEFINER AS
           DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER,                                          
       CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10000) FOR BIT DATA) AS                                             
           DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10000)
 FOR BIT DATA) AS REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE                                         
  FROM SYSTRIGGERS D                                            
  JOIN SYSTABLES T ON T.TABLE_NAME=D.EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE                                         
                  AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA=D.EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA                                          
UNION ALL                                           
SELECT D.OBJECT_SCHEMA AS REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.OBJECT_NAME AS                                            
REQ_OBJECT_NAME,D.OBJECT_TYPE AS REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                           
       D.TRIGGER_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.TRIGGER_NAME AS                                          
           DEP_OBJECT_NAME,'TRIGGER' AS DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                                
       D.SYSTEM_TRIGGER_SCHEMA,T.TRIGGER_PROGRAM_NAME,                                          
       '' OBJECT_CATALOG,T.TRIGGER_DEFINER,                                         
       D.PARM_SIGNATURE AS DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,
        CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10000) FOR BIT DATA) AS
       REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE FROM SYSTRIGDEP D                                          
  JOIN SYSTRIGGERS T ON T.TRIGGER_SCHEMA=D.TRIGGER_SCHEMA AND
  T.TRIGGER_NAME=D.TRIGGER_NAME                                         
UNION ALL                                           
SELECT D.OBJECT_SCHEMA AS REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.OBJECT_NAME AS                                            
REQ_OBJECT_NAME,D.OBJECT_TYPE AS REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                           
       D.VIEW_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,VIEW_NAME AS
      DEP_OBJECT_NAME,'VIEW' AS DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                            
       D.SYSTEM_VIEW_SCHEMA,D.SYSTEM_VIEW_NAME,                                         
       '' OBJECT_CATALOG,V.VIEW_DEFINER,                                            
       D.PARM_SIGNATURE AS DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,
      CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10000)
           FOR BIT DATA) AS REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE                                           
  FROM SYSVIEWDEP D                                         
  JOIN SYSVIEWS V ON V.TABLE_SCHEMA=D.VIEW_SCHEMA                                           
                 AND V.TABLE_NAME=D.VIEW_NAME                                           
UNION ALL                                           
SELECT D.OBJECT_SCHEMA AS REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,D.OBJECT_NAME AS                                            
REQ_OBJECT_NAME,D.OBJECT_TYPE AS REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                           
       R.ROUTINE_SCHEMA AS DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,R.ROUTINE_NAME AS                                          
           DEP_OBJECT_NAME,R.ROUTINE_TYPE AS DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                           
       '' SYSTEM_VIEW_NAME,                                         
       '' SYSTEM_VIEW_SCHEMA,                                           
       OBJECT_CATALOG AS REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,R.ROUTINE_DEFINER,                                          
       D.PARM_SIGNATURE AS DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,
       R.PARM_SIGNATURE AS REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE                                            
  FROM SYSROUTINEDEP D                                          
  JOIN SYSROUTINES R ON R.SPECIFIC_NAME=D.SPECIFIC_NAME                                             
                    AND R.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA=D.SPECIFIC_SCHEMA                                         
),                                          
DEPENDENCY_CHAIN_TOP AS (                                           
SELECT REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,REQ_OBJECT_NAME,REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                           
DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_NAME,DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                                  
DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME,                                            
REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER,                                          
DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,                                            
1 AS LEVEL                                          
  FROM DEPENDENCY_CHAIN_BASE                                            
 WHERE REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA IN ('*LIBL','KAL1D')                                           
   AND REQ_OBJECT_NAME='"PARTS"'                                            
   AND REQ_OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE'  -- Optional                                         
),                                          
DEPENDENCY_CHAIN (REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,REQ_OBJECT_NAME,REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                            
DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_NAME,DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                                  
DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME,
REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER,DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,                                            
REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,LEVEL)                                            
AS (                                            
SELECT REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,REQ_OBJECT_NAME,REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                           
DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_NAME,DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                                  
DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME,                                            
REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER,DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,                                            
REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,LEVEL                                         
  FROM DEPENDENCY_CHAIN_TOP                                         
UNION ALL                                           
SELECT d.REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA,d.REQ_OBJECT_NAME,d.REQ_OBJECT_TYPE,                                         
d.DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,d.DEP_OBJECT_NAME,d.DEP_OBJECT_TYPE,                                                
d.DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_SCHEMA,d.DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME,                                            
d.REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,d.DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER,
d.DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,                                            
d.REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE,b.LEVEL+1 AS LEVEL                                          
  FROM DEPENDENCY_CHAIN b                                           
  JOIN DEPENDENCY_CHAIN_BASE d ON d.REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA
                              IN (b.DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,'*LIBL')
                              AND d.REQ_OBJECT_NAME=b.DEP_OBJECT_NAME                                           
                              AND (d.DEP_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE=                                         
        b.REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE OR b.REQ_OBJECT_PARM_SIGNATURE IS NULL)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_NAME SET SortOrder   <--------
CYCLE DEP_OBJECT_SCHEMA,DEP_OBJECT_NAME,DEP_OBJECT_TYPE                                     
SET DuplicateError To '*' Default ' '
SELECT d.REQ_OBJECT_SCHEMA into OBJECT_SCHEMA ,                                         
       REQ_OBJECT_NAME into OBJECT_NAME
       REQ_OBJECT_TYPE into OBJECT_TYPE,
        DuplicateError into DupX
  FROM DEPENDENCY_CHAIN d                                           
 ORDER BY SortOrder;

End;
```

I can't work out the compilation error.
Compilation error is on line 145: Position 1 Keyword SEARCH not expected. Valid tokens: )
FETCH LIMIT ORDER UNION EXCEPT OFFSET.

any ideas how to solve or better structure it?

Comment: what version of IBM i?

Comment: your code doesn't make sense, I'd expect to see multiple rows returned.  You do that in a Db2 stored proc by returning an open cursor, not with output parms.

Comment: IBM i version is 7.4. So are you saying I can't do this ?

Comment: If I just enter in interactive SQL i get a "Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: ) FETCH LIMIT" removing the Create Proc and 'into statements.

Comment: So SQL error messages are notoriously bad at actually telling you where the real problem is. Instead they tell you where the parser got hung up. But the problem looks like a type early in the SQL statement. If you go back and format the SQL statement so that each column is on it's own line, you will come across the error before you get to the second union. This points out the importance of proper formatting of code. If you can't read it well enough to find the typos, you need to format it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you are missing a `)`  to close out the `DEPENDENCY_CHAIN` CTE subselct

I would suggest getting the select statement working before trying to encapsulate it in a procedure.

```
         from dependency_chain b
              join dependency_chain_base d
                on d.req_object_schema in (b.dep_object_schema, '*LIBL')
                  and d.req_object_name = b.dep_object_name
                  and (d.dep_object_parm_signature = b.req_object_parm_signature
                    or b.req_object_parm_signature is null)
     ) -- <-- THIS ONE
       search depth first by dep_object_schema
                             ,dep_object_name set sortorder cycle dep_object_schema
                                                                  ,dep_object_name
                                                                  ,dep_object_type set
       duplicateerror to '*' default ' '
  select d.req_object_schema
         ,req_object_name
         ,req_object_type
         ,duplicateerror
    from dependency_chain d
    order by sortorder;
```

You got another typo here:

```
D.SYSTEM_TABLE_NAME AS DEP_OBJECT_SYSTEM_NAME,
 AS REQ_OBJECT_CATALOG,T.TABLE_DEFINER AS DEP_OBJECT_DEFINER,
```

This works (or at least returns data) for me...

```
with dependency_chain_base (req_object_schema, req_object_name, req_object_type, dep_object_schema,
         dep_object_name, dep_object_type, dep_object_system_schema, dep_object_system_name,
         req_object_catalog, dep_object_definer, dep_object_parm_signature,
         req_object_parm_signature) as (
       select d.object_schema as req_object_schema
              ,d.object_name as req_object_name
              ,d.object_type as req_object_type
              ,d.variable_schema as dep_object_schema
              ,d.variable_name as dep_object_name
              ,'VARIABLE' as dep_object_type
              ,system_var_schema as dep_object_system_schema
              ,system_var_name as dep_object_system_name
              ,'' as req_object_catalog
              ,v.variable_definer as dep_object_definer
              ,d.parm_signature as dep_object_parm_signature
              ,cast(null as varchar(10000) for bit data) as req_object_parm_signature
         from sysvariabledep d
              join sysvariables v
                on v.variable_name = d.variable_name
                  and v.variable_schema = d.variable_schema
       union all
       select d.object_schema as req_object_schema
              ,d.object_name as req_object_name
              ,d.object_type as req_object_type
              ,d.table_schema as dep_object_schema
              ,d.table_name as dep_object_name
              ,'MATERIALIZED QUERY TABLE' as dep_object_type
              ,d.system_table_schema as dep_object_system_schema
              ,d.system_table_name as dep_object_system_name
              ,t.base_table_catalog as req_object_catalog
              ,t.table_definer as dep_object_definer
              ,d.parm_signature as dep_object_parm_signature
              ,cast(null as varchar(10000) for bit data) as req_object_parm_signature
         from systabledep d
              join systables t
                on t.table_name = d.table_name
                  and t.table_schema = d.table_schema
       union all
       select d.event_object_schema as req_object_schema
              ,d.event_object_table as req_object_name
              ,case t.table_type
                when 'A' then 'ALIAS'
                when 'L' then 'LF'
                when 'M' then 'MATERIALIZED QUERY TABLE'
                when 'P' then 'PF'
                when 'T' then 'TABLE'
                when 'V' then 'VIEW'
                else 'OTHER'
              end as req_object_type
              ,d.trigger_schema as dep_object_schema
              ,d.trigger_name as dep_object_name
              ,'TRIGGER' as dep_object_type
              ,system_trigger_schema as dep_object_system_schema
              ,trigger_program_name as dep_object_system_name
              ,base_table_catalog as req_object_catalog
              ,d.trigger_definer as dep_object_definer
              ,cast(null as varchar(10000) for bit data) as dep_object_parm_signature
              ,cast(null as varchar(10000) for bit data) as req_object_parm_signature
         from systriggers d
              join systables t
                on t.table_name = d.event_object_table
                  and t.table_schema = d.event_object_schema
       union all
       select d.object_schema as req_object_schema
              ,d.object_name as req_object_name
              ,d.object_type as req_object_type
              ,d.trigger_schema as dep_object_schema
              ,d.trigger_name as dep_object_name
              ,'TRIGGER' as dep_object_type
              ,d.system_trigger_schema
              ,t.trigger_program_name
              ,'' object_catalog
              ,t.trigger_definer
              ,d.parm_signature as dep_object_parm_signature
              ,cast(null as varchar(10000) for bit data) as req_object_parm_signature
         from systrigdep d
              join systriggers t
                on t.trigger_schema = d.trigger_schema
                  and t.trigger_name = d.trigger_name
       union all
       select d.object_schema as req_object_schema
              ,d.object_name as req_object_name
              ,d.object_type as req_object_type
              ,d.view_schema as dep_object_schema
              ,view_name as dep_object_name
              ,'VIEW' as dep_object_type
              ,d.system_view_schema
              ,d.system_view_name
              ,'' object_catalog
              ,v.view_definer
              ,d.parm_signature as dep_object_parm_signature
              ,cast(null as varchar(10000) for bit data) as req_object_parm_signature
         from sysviewdep d
              join sysviews v
                on v.table_schema = d.view_schema
                  and v.table_name = d.view_name
       union all
       select d.object_schema as req_object_schema
              ,d.object_name as req_object_name
              ,d.object_type as req_object_type
              ,r.routine_schema as dep_object_schema
              ,r.routine_name as dep_object_name
              ,r.routine_type as dep_object_type
              ,'' system_view_name
              ,'' system_view_schema
              ,object_catalog as req_object_catalog
              ,r.routine_definer
              ,d.parm_signature as dep_object_parm_signature
              ,r.parm_signature as req_object_parm_signature
         from sysroutinedep d
              join sysroutines r
                on r.specific_name = d.specific_name
                  and r.specific_schema = d.specific_schema
     )
     ,dependency_chain_top as (
       select req_object_schema
              ,req_object_name
              ,req_object_type
              ,dep_object_schema
              ,dep_object_name
              ,dep_object_type
              ,dep_object_system_schema
              ,dep_object_system_name
              ,req_object_catalog
              ,dep_object_definer
              ,dep_object_parm_signature
              ,req_object_parm_signature
              ,1 as mylevel
         from dependency_chain_base
         where req_object_schema in ('MYLIB')
               and req_object_name = 'MYFILE'
               and req_object_type = 'TABLE' -- Optional
     )
     ,
     dependency_chain (req_object_schema, req_object_name, req_object_type, dep_object_schema,
         dep_object_name, dep_object_type, dep_object_system_schema, dep_object_system_name,
         req_object_catalog, dep_object_definer, dep_object_parm_signature,
         req_object_parm_signature, mylevel) as (
       select req_object_schema
              ,req_object_name
              ,req_object_type
              ,dep_object_schema
              ,dep_object_name
              ,dep_object_type
              ,dep_object_system_schema
              ,dep_object_system_name
              ,req_object_catalog
              ,dep_object_definer
              ,dep_object_parm_signature
              ,req_object_parm_signature
              ,1 as mylevel
         from dependency_chain_top
       union all
       select d.req_object_schema
              ,d.req_object_name
              ,d.req_object_type
              ,d.dep_object_schema
              ,d.dep_object_name
              ,d.dep_object_type
              ,d.dep_object_system_schema
              ,d.dep_object_system_name
              ,d.req_object_catalog
              ,d.dep_object_definer
              ,d.dep_object_parm_signature
              ,d.req_object_parm_signature
              ,b.mylevel + 1 as mylevel
         from dependency_chain b
              join dependency_chain_base d
                on d.req_object_schema in (b.dep_object_schema, '*LIBL')
                  and d.req_object_name = b.dep_object_name
                  and (d.dep_object_parm_signature = b.req_object_parm_signature
                    or b.req_object_parm_signature is null)
     )
       search depth first by dep_object_schema
                             ,dep_object_name set sortorder cycle dep_object_schema
                                                                  ,dep_object_name
                                                                  ,dep_object_type set
       duplicateerror to '*' default ' '
  select *
    from dependency_chain d
    order by sortorder;
```

**Note** don't use `level` as a column name it's a keyword..

Lastly, to make the above into a stored proc, you'd simply

```
declare depGraph cursor for <statement>;
open depGraph;
return;
```